# Is there way to return actual x,y-coordinates from the image?

Tags: python, tkinter

my dear py-experts.
I wrote a GUI program in python (Tkinter library) which displays a picture, to display an image i used the Canvas widget. The program does load a picture (its width/height always bigger than Canvas width/height) and when i make a mouse click on the Canvas it returns a x,y - coordinates (and color grayscale value), but it always a coordinates of Canvas, not an image ones. For example - image sizes are x=5040 and y=3360 and Canvas widget sizes are x=500 and y=400 and when i making a click on Canvas i never get values,even if i scrolling image, more than 500 for X-axis and 400 for Y-axis respectively.  What i did wrong, how to get right information from the image?
Thnx.

Comment: First, you forgot to show code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs on [`Canvas`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) explain:

> **Coordinate Systems**
>
> The **`Canvas`** widget uses two coordinate systems; the window coordinate system (with (0, 0) in the upper left corner), and a canvas coordinate system which specify where the items are drawn. By scrolling the canvas, you can specify which part of the canvas coordinate system to show in the window.
>
> The **scrollregion** option is used to limit scrolling operations for the canvas. To set this, you can usually use something like:

```
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
```

> To convert from window coordinates to canvas coordinates, use the [`canvasx`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.canvasx-method) and [`canvasy`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.canvasy-method) methods:

```
def callback(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print canvas.find_closest(x, y)
```

Note that this will give you *canvas* coordinates, which are not necessarily the same as *image* coordinate—if you, e.g., left a border around the image within the canvas, you will have to correct for that manually.

Comment: abarnert, u gave me a good hint about how to solve the problem, canvasx/canvasy did everything correctly. Thank u, buddy ;)